# MULE ESB Export Query Result to CSV

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio

I've builded a simple REST API with two resources. One to recover a collection of Trips (GET /trips) and another to recover trips to a certain place (GET /trips/{place}. Both recover data from a MySql database. The API is working y can execute both queries and return the results but I'd like to export DATA to a CSV file.

I need a HINT about how to export the resultset to a CSV file. Should I need a transformer or an object to string component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dataweave (Transform Message) to reach it. See some examples here: https://estebanwasinger.wordpress.com/2015/12/31/dataweave-examples-transform-json-and-xml-list-to-csv/

Try it and we will help you if you get stuck.

Comment: Victor, thanks for the HINT. I solved using an object-toson then the transform message to convert to csv and finally befor saving to a file an object to string. I dont know if the same can be done with less components-